# Exclude folders from the build in a publishproj in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild

Is there anyway to exclude folders from the build in a publishproj in Visual Studio 2013?

There's a folder that contains over 6,000 static HTML, JS, CSS & IMG files which slows down the build. To complicate things these files are included in source control (TFS). I can go through and exclude from project on individual files but can't seem to do it at a folder level.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an option in Visual Studio for this.

You can select multiple files and set thier build action to "none" and set "Copy to Output Directory" option to "Do Not copy".

Also on the Package/Publish web setting for you project, set the option Items to deploy to "Only files 
needed to run this application".

Have a look at this blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2010/04/22/web-deployment-excluding-files-and-folders-via-the-web-application-s-project-file.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for link Hamid, am still not clear on how to do this for a website project in Visual Studio 2013. The link relates to web application project in Visual Studio 2010. Seems like you don't get as many build options using website projects, http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/web-application-project-vs-web-site.html